# Pycaret.regression.compare_models: Evaluation table neither returned nor shown

Tags: python-3.x, pycaret

pycaret is a very compact tool to compare models that I wanted to use for model selection. Unfortunately, the method compare_models does not show the typical [output table](https://i2.wp.com/pycaret.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/classification_compare_models.png?resize=805%2C504&ssl=1) that you see everywhere. I am using pycaret in PyCharm and not Jupyter Notebook which seems to be the typical approach. I do get the best model as a return value, but am really aiming for the overview table. It also doesn't seem to make a difference whether the parameter `silent` is set to `True` or `False` appart from being asked for the confirmation of whether the derived datatypes are correct.

Thank you very much!

The system:
Python 3.6
pycaret 2.3
CentOS 7
PyCharm 2020.1 Community Edition

My code:

```
    regression.setup(data=ml_df,
                     target='occupation',
                     n_jobs=6,
                     categorical_features=['cluster', 'vacation', 'long_weekend', 'month', 'hour', 'weekday'],
                     numeric_features=['temperature', 'precipitation'],
                     silent=False
                     )
    best_regression_models = regression.compare_models()

    categorisation = [
        [-0.1, 'empty'],
        [0.01, 'partial'],
        [0.99, 'full']
    ]
    ml_df['occupation'] = modelling_utils.convert_number_to_categorical(ml_df['occupation'], categorisation)
    classification.setup(data=ml_df,
                         target='occupation',
                         n_jobs=6,
                         categorical_features=['cluster', 'vacation', 'long_weekend', 'month', 'hour', 'weekday'],
                         numeric_features=['temperature', 'precipitation'],
                         fix_imbalance=True,
                         silent=False)
    best_classification_models = classification.compare_models()
```

The full output is somewhat lengthy and saved [here](https://rwth-aachen.sciebo.de/s/eJSWFirezB0tYma).

Edit: The code works as expected in a Jupyter Notebook

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Running PyCaret from a terminal/command line has different behavior compared to running from a Jupyter notebook. In your case, if you want to display the comparison output table, add these 2 lines after your compare_models() function call:

```
..
best_regression_models = regression.compare_models()


regression_results = pull()
print(regression_results)
```

The pull() function will also return the last score grid with other training functions, such as create_model(). Currently this function only works with the regression and classification modules.

Reference: https://pycaret.org/pull/

**UPDATED** References:

- https://pycaret.gitbook.io/docs/get-started/release-notes?q=pull
- https://pycaret.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/regression.html?highlight=pull#pycaret.regression.pull